# Mistake in the solution to the heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I just solved the heat equation but my solution is not the same as the solution given.

Concretely, I am solving

$$ u_t (x,t) = D u_{xx}(x,t) $$ for $x \in (0,1) , t > 0$

with boundary conditions

$$ u_x (0,t) = u_x(1,t) = 0$$

This are equations pertaining to a wire of length $1$ with heat capacity $D>0$.

The problem I have is that I assumed that the period was $1$ because the length of the wire is given as $1$ but the solution I have to this exercise assumes $P=2$ and then for example integrates the Fourier coefficients from $-1$ to $1$.

I don't understand what's going on here.

**Why is the period $2$ and not $1$?**

Comment: A basis for $L^2[0,1]$ with boundary conditions $u_x (t,0)=u_x (t,1)=0$ is $\{ \cos(n\pi x)\}_{n \ge 0}$

Comment: @Vajra Why does $\cos (2 \pi n x)$ not work?

Comment: The book integrates from -1 to 1 because it's making a periodic extension. If only coisines are a basis of the PDE and its boundary conditions, an even extension is needed. If only sines are a basis, an odd extension is needed.

Comment: @Luciano Thank you for your help.